# Table Layout to CSS Layout how to work around colspan?

Tags: html, css

If I create a layout with tables like the old-school way:

```css
input {
    width: 100%;    
    padding: 5px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;  
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><label>Label 1:</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>                               
  <tr>
    <td><label>Label 2:</label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>
    <label>Label 3:</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><label>Label 4:</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><label>Label 5:</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>           
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/njb69anL/

I get a layout where it is like a grid on the screen.  It resizes to the width of the browser easily.  Everything is spaced and placed correctly.

However, my html markup is full of table tags.  If I wanted to rid myself of the table I'd start by making the markup semantic:

```
        <div id="grp">
            <label>Label 1:</label><input type="text" />
            <label>Label 2:</label><input type="text" />
            <label>Label 3:</label><input type="text" />
            <label>Label 4:</label><input type="text" />
            <label>Label 5:</label><input type="text" />            
        </div>
```

But is it even possible to achieve the same table-like layout with this little markup? It seems `display: table` cannot do `colspan`, and the trickiest part is having a row with two label,input pairs on the same row.  Is it possible to achieve this without adding a whole bunch of wrapper `div`s and thus making the original markup messy (non-semantic) anyways?

Comment: Note: input tags are self closing and do not need a closing slash.

Comment: @Rob Depends on the `HTML DOCTYPE` specification declared. The user may have specified `xhtml 1.0 strict`. Thus providing the closing empty elements would be valid, whereas omitting the the closing slash would be invalid markup.

Comment: Tables still exist for a reason. They're intended for tabular data....don't be afraid of tables for their purpose.

Comment: @fyrye This question is tagged as HTML so, no, he is not serving this as XHTML.

Comment: @Rob In HTML5 `<input>` is a *void element* per spec, so the closing slash is valid, but optional.  Probably omitting it is for the best, though.

Comment: @user17753 Yes. It's valid and optional but also serves no purpose, does nothing but take up space, browsers are ordered to ignore it (according to the spec) making it totally pointless. You will find nowhere, in any version of HTML, an example of its use for those tags. Nor is it recommended or encouraged.

Comment: @user17753 Updated my answer using your minimalistic markup approach and css.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.labels-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40%;
}

label {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
label:nth-child(2),
label:nth-child(3) {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="labels-wrapper">
  <label>Label 1:
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>Label 2:
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>Label 3:
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>Label 4:
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>Label 5:
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Adding flexbox example for an alternative.  Please use the "full page" button to really get a feel for how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

You would use css `float` or `inline-block` and `width` percentage to specify the amount of space each row element consumes.

**EDITED CSS Version**

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/njb69anL/3/

In order for this example to work, the label and input positions would need to be next to each other for them to appear on the same row. The end result is your markup looks like the display. Using `nth-child` allows you to specify which element in the list to apply your rule to.

**HTML**

```
<div id="grp">
  <label>Label 1:</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label>Label 2:</label><label>Label 3:</label>
  <input type="text" /><input type="text" />
  <label>Label 4:</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label>Label 5:</label>
  <input type="text" />            
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#grp {
  width: 50%;
}

input,
label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

label:nth-child(3),
label:nth-child(4){
  width: 50%;
}

input:nth-child(5) {
  width: 49%;
}

input:nth-child(6) {
  width: 49%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

---

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/njb69anL/2/

*updated with a responsive layout*

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <div class="full-row">
    <label>
      <span>Label 1:</span>
      <input type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="half-row">
    <label>
      <span>Label 2:</span>
      <input type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="half-row">
    <label>
      <span>Label 3:</span>
      <input type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="full-row">
    <label>
      <span>Label 4:</span>
      <input type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form input{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

form {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

form > div {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.full-row {
  width: 100%;
}

.half-row {
  width: 50%;
}

label > span{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get it looking right using the html above is with `position:absolute` which to me feels like a hack. I have wrapped `label 2` and `label 3` in a `div` so they may be grouped together.

The below html / css gets very close to the fiddle:

```css
#grp {
  width: 50%;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#grp label,
#grp input {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  clear:left;
}
#grp input {
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
#grp div {
  float:left;
  width:49%;
}
#grp div + div {
  margin-left:2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="grp">
  <label>Label 1:</label><input type="text" />
  <div><label>Label 2:</label><input type="text" /></div>
  <div><label>Label 3:</label><input type="text" /></div>
  <label>Label 4:</label><input type="text" />
  <label>Label 5:</label><input type="text" />            
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. I have created a fiddle for you. It's about the same amount of content, but it is definitely more easy to manipulate than a table.

I just use:

```
<wrapper>
    <row>
        <label></label>
        <input>
    </row>
</wrapper>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Kiaaanabal/qv89yb56/